# Difference between Kahler-Einstein and Bergman metric on a bounded symmetric domain

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, lie-groups

Let $H$ be a bounded symmetric domain.

What is the difference between the Bergman metric and the Kahler-Einstein metric on $H$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bergman metric on any bounded symmetric domain is equal to the biholomorphism invariant Kaehler-Einstein metric, which makes it a Hermitian symmetric space. See Mok, **Metric Rigidity Theorems on Hermitian Locally Symmetric Manifolds**, p. 59, proposition 3.

Comment: Of course, you could always rescale the metric by a constant, and it remains Kaehler-Einstein. If the domain splits as a product of domains, this corresponds to a metric splitting into a product of Hermitian symmmetric spaces, and you could rescale each factor by a different positive constant, to get a family of Kaehler-Einstein metrics. But if you want the totally geodesic complete complex disks to have Gauss curvature normalized to -1, then the metric is the Bergman metric.